# logarithm in basis $x$ is it always equal to 1?

Tags: logarithms

Is the logarithm function $ y = \log_{x} (x) $

always '1' for $x > 0$, this is equal to the implicit function $ x=x^{y} $ so $ y=1$

Comment: what about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }+ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: You should specify that $x \neq 1$ since $1^x = 1$ does not have a unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  Due to the logarithm law
$$\log_a b=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_c a}$$ just plug in $a=b$.

However, there are two restrictions: $a$, $b$ and $c$ must be positive; and $a$ and $c$ must not be 1 because log to base 1 makes no sense resp. we would divide by 0 in the fraction above.

Hence the answer to your question is *"yes, but $x$ must not be 1"*.